# How i can make a specific code for a notification in a column?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need that when you write only in a certain cell send me an email from who did it

The code i use is

```
function myFunction() {
  var user = Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
  if(user =='user-email'){
    MailApp.sendEmail('destination-email', 'subject', 'test trigger: ' + user);
  }
}
```

But i need when someone write on the column "D" and only "D" send me a email notification

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Of course, you need to add sheet name, recipient, subject.  And this will mostly like require an installable onEdit() function which means that users that share your spreadsheet will have to authorize it so you won't be able to do it without their permission.

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  if(name!='WhatEverSheetNameYouWant')return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==4) {
    var user=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    if(user) {
      MailApp.sendEmail('recipient', 'subject', 'Test trigger: ' + user);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: TypeError: No se puede leer la propiedad "range" de undefined. (línea 2, archivo "Email") i got that error                                                                                                                                                 And the new code is

Comment: My guess is that your missing the 'e' or your trying to run the function without an event object.